# Location Analysis with Open Street Map Data

Tags: r, geolocation, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am attempting to do some simple location analysis using features available from Open Street Map. In particular, I want to build features related to proximity to major roads and hourly traffic counts. Using a list of locations I need to find the distance to the nearest major road and the traffic estimates on that road. So far I have been unable to extract Key:traffic:hourly from OSM and have not found an efficient way to compute the nearest major road to a location.

The below example is a simple set-up of all the McDonald's in Atlanta and the major roads. What is the best way to find the nearest major road to each location and the OSM traffic estimate of that road?

```
#~~~~~~~~~~Example~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)
library(osmar)
library(sf)

#Query McDonald's in Atlanta
q.ATL<- getbb("Atlanta") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature("amenity", "fast_food")%>%
  add_osm_feature("name", "McDonald's",value_exact = FALSE, match_case = FALSE)%>%
  osmdata_sf()

MDs.info<-as.data.frame(q.ATL[["osm_points"]]) # actually make this a dataframe

# Find Major Roads
MajorRds <- getbb("Atlanta Georgia")%>%
  opq()%>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = c("motorway", "primary", "motorway_link", "primary_link")) %>%
  #add_osm_feature("traffic", "hourly")%>%  # This does not grab the appropriate information
  osmdata_sf()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is probably `st_nearest_feature()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)
library(sf)

#Query McDonald's in Atlanta
q.ATL<- getbb("Atlanta") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature("amenity", "fast_food")%>%
  add_osm_feature("name", "McDonald's",value_exact = FALSE, match_case = FALSE)%>%
  osmdata_sf()

MDs.info <- as.data.frame(q.ATL[["osm_points"]]) |>
  select(osm_id, geometry) |>
  st_as_sf()

# Find Major Roads
MajorRds <- getbb("Atlanta Georgia")%>%
  opq()%>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = c("motorway", "primary", "motorway_link", "primary_link")) %>%
  #add_osm_feature("traffic", "hourly")%>%  # This does not grab the appropriate information
  osmdata_sf()
```

Now, we have to merge `osm_lines` and `osm_multilines` to get all highways:

```r
r <- MajorRds$osm_lines |>
  select(osm_id, name, highway, geometry)

r <- MajorRds$osm_multilines |>
  select(osm_id, name, highway, geometry) |>
  add_row(r)
```

Let's plot it for visualization

```r
plot(r$geometry)
plot(MDs.info, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Now we will use `st_nearest_feature()` to find the nearest way and `st_distance` to calculate how far it is:

```r
nearest <- st_nearest_feature(MDs.info, r)
dist = st_distance(MDs.info, r[nearest,], by_element=TRUE)
MDs.info <- cbind(MDs.info, st_drop_geometry(r)[nearest,])
MDs.info$dist <- dist
head(MDs.info)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 5 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.3696 ymin: 33.7743 xmax: -84.29572 ymax: 33.79026
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>              osm_id osm_id.1                name       highway
#> 497203850 497203850 40861481      Clairmont Road       primary
#> 534028686 534028686  9249238                <NA> motorway_link
#> 544125305 544125305 74927688 East College Avenue       primary
#> 654308248 654308248 74927688 East College Avenue       primary
#> 654308249 654308249 74927688 East College Avenue       primary
#> 654308250 654308250 74927688 East College Avenue       primary
#>                             geometry           dist
#> 497203850 POINT (-84.30741 33.79026)   86.16797 [m]
#> 534028686   POINT (-84.3696 33.7743) 1586.02491 [m]
#> 544125305 POINT (-84.29574 33.77833)  856.44432 [m]
#> 654308248 POINT (-84.29574 33.77831)  854.60091 [m]
#> 654308249 POINT (-84.29572 33.77831)  854.08773 [m]
#> 654308250 POINT (-84.29573 33.77804)  826.30178 [m]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The issue with `key=traffic:hourly` is, it's not popular  and very seldom used, see https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/?key=traffic%3Ahourly

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much as this answer my question beautifully.